# How to add text to user input - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input where users can enter a price. When the user presses a number key, I want to prepend whatever they type with a '£' sign.

Like this but visible in the input field, not just bound to a data property:

```
// empty
£1 // first keydown
£12
£125
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Knights/6xn12tj9/6/

Any ideas how to achieve this? Tried a few things but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set your input type to number. so you can only use number.

But if you want to force user to enter only number, you can do this:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" :placeholder="placeholderPrice" v-model="price" @keypress="mustNumber"/>
  <div class="price">
    <p v-if="price !== ''">
    </p>
    {{ price }}
  </div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    price: "£",
  },
  methods: {
        inputPrice(e) {
        this.price = `£${e.target.value}`;
    },
    mustNumber($event) {
            let keyCode = $event.keyCode ? $event.keyCode : $keyCode;

            // only allow number and one dot
            if (
                (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) &&
                (keyCode !== 46)
            ) {
                $event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
  }
})
```

Comment: Tweeked your answer a bit and this works really well: https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Knights/6xn12tj9/32/

Comment: It's also worth noting that keycodes are slightly different depending on which browser you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Daniel I think you might need to change type="number" to text to allow you to use a non numeric value

Comment: Thank you Jev! Changed it to this and now it works: https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Knights/6xn12tj9/11/

Answer (score 0):

You need masked input. For example you can use https://vuejs-tips.github.io/v-money/ library

```
<template>
  <div>
    <money v-model="price" v-bind="money"></money> {{price}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {Money} from 'v-money'

  export default {
    components: {Money},

    data () {
      return {
        price: 123.45,
        money: {
        decimal: ',',
        thousands: '.',
        prefix: '£ ',
        suffix: '',
        precision: 2,
        masked: false
      }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```